# Xcode 12 autocomplete is broken

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

I want to enter "append". What I expected is that when I enter "app", autocomplete should prompt a list, but autocomplete doesn't show any functions of Array. I even tried to press ESC to show autocompletes manually. I got no luck.

```
struct MyPackage {
    var xs = [Int]()
    xs.append(
}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to enter code outside of an executable context.  Try putting the append inside a `func` and autocomplete should work fine.